# Python versions are not changing despite activating virtual environment in WSL2

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, wsl-2

**Background:**

In WSL2 (ubuntu 20.04) I created a python virtual environment inside a directory. Using the command `python3 -m venv venv` my system's python version was set to python3.11 (after downloading) via `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and then choosing the version. I noticed I was having some errors of missing modules when I started WSL2 (happening after a computer restart), I read this was because I was using a different python version than the one ubuntu 20.04 came with so I switched back to 3.8 via the config menu as before. I am also using VS code that's connected to my WSL2.

These are some of the contents of my venv directory: `venv/bin/python` `venv/bin/python3` `venv/bin/python3.11` `venv/bin/pip` `venv/bin/pip3`

**Question:**

After activating my virutal env via `source venv/bin/activate`, when I do `python3 --version` I still get a version of 3.8.10 despite creating the virtual environment with 3.11. I was able to get the interpretor set to 3.11 on VS code.I know I was in the virtual environment since my command prompt had (venv) in front. I went into the python console while in the virtual env and did `import sys` and `sys.path` this was my output `['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload']`. **Why isn't the python version changing, am I misunderstanding something or did I not do something correctly?** Seems like pip isn't working either but works when I switch my system python to 3.11 (I tried installing it on 3.8 but it said it was already installed).

**Solved:**

Answered below, just re-created the virtual env while making sure my system python version was 3.11 (may have been some mixup earlier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the selection in `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` you change the selected python version also for the chosen vitrual environment (at least when using `venv`, it might be different with other tools).

That can cause issues, because when creating a new virtual environment `envname` using `venv` from a specific python version `xx.xx`, a directory named `pythonxx.xx` is created in `/envname/lib/`, and inside it a directory named `site-packages` that contains the packages installed by the `pip` of this specific environment.

So changing back to the original python version of the environment through `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` should solve the issue, and probably the errors of missing modules are due to the incompatibility of the current selected python version with the original version which you installed the virtual environment from.

Personally, to avoid confusing, I name my virtual environments with the python version as a suffix, e.g `envname_py3.11.1`. But there might be a better method which I am not aware of.

Comment: Ah makes sense, is there a "better" way to change the system version so it doesn't change virtual environment version as well? I was previously getting an error for a missing netifaces module, even after installing it. Oddly enough it seemed to have resolved after trying to recreate the error with python3.11

Comment: I have edited my answer with a clarification. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my venv directory and recreated my virtual environment while on python3.11. This has resolved my issue.